# TypeError: Cannot read property of send (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, discord, discord.js

I have a problem with `audit-logs` in `discord.js`. I have problem with messageUptade. Here is my code form `messageUpdate`:

```
const Event = require('../structures/Event');
const { MessageEmbed, Util: { escapeMarkdown } } = require('discord.js');
const { diffWordsWithSpace } = require('diff');
const colors = require('../colors.json');
const { stripIndents } = require('common-tags');

module.exports = class extends Event {

    async run(message, old) {
        
        if (!message.guild || old.content === message.content || message.author.bot) return;

        const logs = this.client.database.getLogs(message.guild.id);
        const logsID = this.client.database.getLogsID(message.channel.id);
        const logsCH = message.client.channels.cache.get(logsID);

        if (!logs) {
            
            return;

        } else {

            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(colors.orange)
            .setAuthor(`Message Updated`)
            .setTitle(old.author.tag, old.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .setDescription(stripIndents`
            **❯ Message ID:** ${old.id}
            **❯ Channel:** ${old.channel}
            **❯ Author:** ${old.author.tag} (${old.author.id})
            `)
            .setFooter(`${message.guild.name} Logs`, message.guild.iconURL())
            .setTimestamp()
            .setURL(old.url)
            .addField(`**❯ Updated Message Content:**`, diffWordsWithSpace(escapeMarkdown(old.content), escapeMarkdown(message.content))
            .map(result => result.added ? `**${result.value}**` : result.removed ? `~~${result.value}~~` : `${result.value}`)
            .join(' '));

            logsCH.send(embed);

            
        };
    }
}
```

And here is database code:

```
getLogs(id) {
        let query = 'SELECT * FROM logs WHERE guildid = ?';
        const row = db.prepare(query).get(id);
        if (row === undefined) {
            return;
        } else {
            return row;
        }
    }

    getLogsID(id) {
        let query = 'SELECT channelid FROM logs WHERE guildid = ?';
        const row = db.prepare(query).get(id);
        if (row === undefined) {
            return;
        } else {
            return row.channelid;
        }
    }
```

I have `TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined.`

Can we help me?

Answer (score 0):

The logs channel is not found, because you used `message.client` instead of `message.guild` Thats why it is `undefined`.

You should change your code of getting the channel to:

```
const logsCH = message.guild.channels.cache.get(logsID);
```